# Phone still stuck in a bootloop after flashing official firmware with Odin!

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, data-recovery, boot-loop, odin

I *successfully* flashed a stock ROM on my Galaxy Note 4 using Odin 3.13.1 but, unfortunatelly, the bootloop is not gone.

**Device info**:

- SM-N910C
- unrooted
- Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow

**Bootloop sequence**: Samsung boot screen **—>** Android is starting... Optimising Apps 2 of 2. **—>** Android is starting... Starting apps. **—>** LOOP

**What are my options to restore my personal data from now on?**

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that you have not wiped your data while flashing firmware using Odin, the process of data retrieval can be variably difficult. 
The best way I can think of is to **flash a custom recovery on your device** then **mount** desired partitions.
PS I have no information whether your phone is rooted or not, so just providing the most workable way.

Comment: Wouldn't flashing anything other than the stock ROM wipe out the data anyway? Or custom recovery is something different?

Comment: Custom recoveries, when flashed correctly, only overwrite the recovery partition.

Comment: I see. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @Rayhunter Recommendations regarding recovery? TWRP.

Comment: Will unlocking the bootloader wipe out my personal data? I was left under the impression that it actually did. If so, is there a way to install TWRP without unlocking the BL?